Same code with listing works and doesn't work
I was using Latex a lot, and I thought that I can figure out many questions, but this one was a big surprise for me.
I have a code from this article (I deleted some not relevant parts):
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\pdfoutput=1


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{cmbright} \usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} \usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{dsfont} \usepackage{enumitem} \usepackage{attachfile2}
\usepackage{xifthen} %\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{qcircuit}

\usepackage[nopostdot,toc]{glossaries}

% page layout: fit more onto one page
\semiisopage[12]
\checkandfixthelayout



\renewcommand{\idtextinnotes}[1]{#1\space}
\notepageref
\makepagenote
\let\oldpagenote\pagenote
\newcommand{\startsolutions}{\let\pagenote\oldpagenote}
\newcommand{\stopsolutions}{\renewcommand{\pagenote}[2][]{}}
%\stopsolutions

% some Pantone colors
\definecolor{livingcoral}{HTML}{FA7268}         % pantone color of the year 2019: 16-1546 Living Coral
\definecolor{ultraviolet}{HTML}{5F4B8B}         % pantone color of the year 2018: 18-3838 Ultra Violet
\definecolor{greenery}{HTML}{88B04B}            % pantone color of the year 2017: 15-0343 Greenery
\definecolor{radiantorchid}{HTML}{AD5E99}       % pantone color of the year 2014: 18-3224 Radiant Orchid
\definecolor{tangerinetango}{HTML}{DD4124}      % pantone color of the year 2011: 17-1463 Tangerine Tango

% the color scheme for Mathematica code
\definecolor{mathematicacolor}{rgb}{0,0,0.9}            % Mathematica code in text
\definecolor{mathematicacommentcolor}{rgb}{0.3,0.6,0.7} % Mathematica comments
\definecolor{mathematicaprintcolor}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}       % Mathematica Print[] output
\definecolor{mathematicaerrorcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}         % Mathematica errors
\definecolor{mathematicaechocolor}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}        % Mathematica echo
\definecolor{mathematicalinenumbercolor}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}  % Mathematica line numbers
\definecolor{mathematicainoutcolor}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}   % Mathematica In[] and Out[] prefixes

% the color scheme for links etc.
\colorlet{questionscolor}{greenery}                 % questions/exercises (used to be {rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.2})
\colorlet{linkcolor}{radiantorchid}                 % all hyperlinks (used to be {rgb}{0.9,0,0.3})
    \colorlet{internallinkcolor}{linkcolor}             % internal hyperlinks
    \colorlet{externallinkcolor}{linkcolor}             % external hyperlinks
\colorlet{embeddedcodecolor}{tangerinetango}            % links to embedded Mathematica code file (used to be {rgb}{1,0.5,0})
\newcommand{\embeddedcodecolorname}{orange}     % string for referring to the links in the text

% color scheme for titles
\colorlet{chapternumbercolor}{ultraviolet}
\colorlet{chaptertitlecolor}{ultraviolet}

% color all links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={internallinkcolor},
    urlcolor={externallinkcolor},
    pdfauthor={Roman Schmied},
%    pdftitle={Introduction to Computational Quantum Mechanics},
    pdftitle={Using Mathematica for Quantum Mechanics - A Student's Manual}
    pdfdisplaydoctitle,
    pdfsubject={Quantum mechanical calculations with Wolfram Mathematica},
    pdfkeywords={quantum mechanics, Wolfram Mathematica}
}

% parentheses around equation numbers when using \autoref
\let\oldtheequation\theequation
    \makeatletter
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr}}
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{(\oldtheequation)}
    \makeatother

% use \emdash instead of --- so that the hyphenation works properly:
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak---\nobreak\hskip0pt}
% allow hyphenation of words containing a hyphen
\hyphenchar\font=\string"7F

% dummy counter for getting \autopageref hyperlinks to point to the correct page
\newcounter{dummy}

% hyphenation

% use small figures?
\newboolean{smallfigures}
\setboolean{smallfigures}{true}

% attached Mathematica code
\newcommand{\listattachmentsname}{list of attached notebooks}
\newlistof{listofattachments}{att}{\listattachmentsname}
\newcounter{attachments}
%\newcommand{\attachcode}[2]{\refstepcounter{attachments}{\color{embeddedcodecolor}[}\textattachfile{code/#1.nb}{code}{\color{embeddedcodecolor}]}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{att}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theattachments.}\textbf{#1.nb} --- #2}}
\newcommand{\attachcode}[2]{\refstepcounter{attachments}{\color{embeddedcodecolor}[}\textattachfile{#1.nb}{code}{\color{embeddedcodecolor}]}\addcontentsline{att}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theattachments.}\textbf{#1.nb} --- #2}}
\attachfilesetup{description={Double-click to open in Mathematica.}, print=false, color=embeddedcodecolor, mimetype=application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica}

% style of the chapter headings
\newcommand{\circlenumber}[1]{\raisebox{2pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-2pt}{#1}}}}
\makechapterstyle{graychapters}{% based on the bianchi style
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{}
%   \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont\centering chapter}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont\centering}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\normalfont\fontsize{100}{100}\selectfont{\color{chapternumbercolor}\textbf{\thechapter}}}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\HUGE}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{{\color{chaptertitlecolor}\hrule\vskip\onelineskip\centering\chaptitlefont\textbf{##1}\par}}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{{\color{chaptertitlecolor}\vskip\onelineskip\hrule\vskip\afterchapskip}}}
%\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\chapterstyle{graychapters}

% chapter pictures
%\newcommand{\chapterpicture}[1]{
%   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%       \node[shift={(0,-0.3\textwidth)}] at (current page.north){\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{#1}};
%   \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\chapterpicture}[1]{
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=0.33\textheight]{#1}
    \end{center}}

% number subsections as well, but not subsubsections
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
% make the subsections appear in the TOC
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
% call subsections sections when autorefing them in the text:
\let\subsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname
\let\subsubsectionautorefname\sectionautorefname



% make symbols that can be used inside of Mathematica code and that can be copy-pasted into Mathematica
% the new symbols are called \mmalpha etc.
% For example, \mmalpha shows as "\textalpha" in LaTeX and as "\[Alpha]" in the clipboard when copying out of the PDF, so that pasting into Mathematica yields an alpha symbol.
\newcommand{\makemathematicasymbol}[3]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname mm#1\endcsname{\protect\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,ActualText=\textbackslash\relax[#3]}#2\protect\EndAccSupp{}}}
%\newcommand{\myrho}{\protect\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,ActualText=\textbackslash\relax[Rho]}\textrho\protect\EndAccSupp{}}
\makemathematicasymbol{alpha}{\textalpha}{Alpha}
\makemathematicasymbol{beta}{\textbeta}{Beta}
\makemathematicasymbol{gamma}{\textgamma}{Gamma}
\makemathematicasymbol{delta}{\textdelta}{Delta}
\makemathematicasymbol{epsilon}{\textepsilon}{Epsilon}
\makemathematicasymbol{zeta}{\textzeta}{Zeta}
\makemathematicasymbol{eta}{\texteta}{Eta}
\makemathematicasymbol{theta}{\texttheta}{Theta}
\makemathematicasymbol{iota}{\textiota}{Iota}
\makemathematicasymbol{kappa}{\textkappa}{Kappa}
\makemathematicasymbol{lambda}{\textlambda}{Lambda}
\makemathematicasymbol{mu}{\textmu}{Mu}
\makemathematicasymbol{nu}{\textnu}{Nu}
\makemathematicasymbol{xi}{\textxi}{Xi}
\makemathematicasymbol{omikron}{\textomikron}{Omicron}
\makemathematicasymbol{pi}{\textpi}{Pi}
\makemathematicasymbol{rho}{\textrho}{Rho}
\makemathematicasymbol{sigma}{\textsigma}{Sigma}
\makemathematicasymbol{tau}{\texttau}{Tau}
\makemathematicasymbol{upsilon}{\textupsilon}{Upsilon}
\makemathematicasymbol{phi}{\textphi}{Phi}
\makemathematicasymbol{chi}{\textchi}{Chi}
\makemathematicasymbol{psi}{\textpsi}{Psi}
\makemathematicasymbol{omega}{\textomega}{Omega}
\makemathematicasymbol{Alpha}{\textAlpha}{CapitalAlpha}
\makemathematicasymbol{Beta}{\textBeta}{CapitalBeta}
\makemathematicasymbol{Gamma}{\textGamma}{CapitalGamma}
\makemathematicasymbol{Delta}{\textDelta}{CapitalDelta}
\makemathematicasymbol{Epsilon}{\textEpsilon}{CapitalEpsilon}
\makemathematicasymbol{Zeta}{\textZeta}{CapitalZeta}
\makemathematicasymbol{Eta}{\textEta}{CapitalEta}
\makemathematicasymbol{Theta}{\textTheta}{CapitalTheta}
\makemathematicasymbol{Iota}{\textIota}{CapitalIota}
\makemathematicasymbol{Kappa}{\textKappa}{CapitalKappa}
\makemathematicasymbol{Lambda}{\textLambda}{CapitalLambda}
\makemathematicasymbol{Mu}{\textMu}{CapitalMu}
\makemathematicasymbol{Nu}{\textNu}{CapitalNu}
\makemathematicasymbol{Xi}{\textXi}{CapitalXi}
\makemathematicasymbol{Omikron}{\textOmikron}{CapitalOmicron}
\makemathematicasymbol{Pi}{\textPi}{CapitalPi}
\makemathematicasymbol{Rho}{\textRho}{CapitalRho}
\makemathematicasymbol{Sigma}{\textSigma}{CapitalSigma}
\makemathematicasymbol{Tau}{\textTau}{CapitalTau}
\makemathematicasymbol{Upsilon}{\textUpsilon}{CapitalUpsilon}
\makemathematicasymbol{Phi}{\textPhi}{CapitalPhi}
\makemathematicasymbol{Chi}{\textChi}{CapitalChi}       % doesn't work for some reason - is \textChi not defined in the [euler]{textgreek} font?
\makemathematicasymbol{Psi}{\textPsi}{CapitalPsi}
\makemathematicasymbol{Omega}{\textOmega}{CapitalOmega}
\makemathematicasymbol{hbar}{\ensuremath{\hbar}}{HBar}
\makemathematicasymbol{infty}{\ensuremath{\infty}}{Infinity}
\makemathematicasymbol{times}{\ensuremath{\times}}{Times}

\newcommand{\ix}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ex}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\text{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\ie}{\emph{i.e.}}
\newcommand{\eg}{\emph{e.g.}}
\newcommand{\etal}{\emph{et al.}}

\newcommand{\myurl}[1]{{\scriptsize{\url{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\Eunit}{\mathcal{E}}    % energy unit
\newcommand{\tunit}{\mathcal{T}}    % time unit
\newcommand{\lunit}{\mathcal{L}}    % length unit
\newcommand{\punit}{\mathcal{P}}    % momentum unit
\newcommand{\munit}{\mathcal{M}}    % mass unit

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\round}{round}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ai}{Ai}

%\newcommand{\R}{$^{\textregistered}$}
\newcommand{\R}{$^{\circledR}$}
\newcommand{\AdobeReader}{Adobe\R\ Acrobat\R\ Reader\R}
\newcommand{\AdobeReaderLink}{\href{https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/pdf-reader.html}{\AdobeReader}}

% use this to indicate the lecture transitions
%\newcounter{lecturecounter}
%\newcommand{\lectureend}{\refstepcounter{lecturecounter}{\color{green}\emph{END OF LECTURE \thelecturecounter}}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect{\color{green}\qquad\qquad end of lecture \thelecturecounter}}}
%\newcommand{\lectureend}{}

% the command character inside Mathematica code is ¤, in order not to interfere with Mathematica code
% bracketing (for labels) inside Mathematica code is with Ž and 
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{mathematica}{Verbatim}{gobble=1,numbers=left,numbersep=2mm,formatcom=\color{mathematicacolor},%
    fontfamily=tt,frame=single,commandchars=¤Ž}
\newcommand{\mathbox}[1]{\parbox{1.03cm}{#1}}       % for 10pt
%\newcommand{\mathbox}[1]{\parbox{1.18cm}{#1}}      % for 12pt
%\newcounter{mathincounter}[chapter]
\newcounter{mathincounter}
\newcounter{mathoutcounter} % new
\renewcommand{\themathincounter}{In[\arabic{mathincounter}]}
%\newcommand{\themathoutcounter}{Out[\arabic{mathincounter}]}
\renewcommand{\themathoutcounter}{Out[\arabic{mathoutcounter}]}
%\newcommand{\mathin}{\refstepcounter{mathincounter}\setcounter{mathoutcounter}{\value{mathincounter}-1}\mathbox{\scriptsize\themathincounter:=}}
\newcommand{\mathin}{\refstepcounter{mathincounter}\setcounter{mathoutcounter}{\value{mathincounter}-1}\protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\mathbox{\scriptsize\color{mathematicainoutcolor}\themathincounter:=}\protect\EndAccSupp{}}
%\newcommand{\mathout}{\refstepcounter{mathoutcounter}\mathbox{\scriptsize\themathoutcounter=}}
\newcommand{\mathout}{\refstepcounter{mathoutcounter}\protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\mathbox{\scriptsize\color{mathematicainoutcolor}\themathoutcounter=}\protect\EndAccSupp{}}
\newcommand{\mathnl}{\mathbox{\rule{0mm}{0mm}}}                         % newline with correct indentation
\newcommand{\mathnlc}{\color{mathematicacommentcolor}\mathbox{\rule{0mm}{0mm}}} % newline with correct indentation, only for comments! (different color)
\newcommand{\mathnlp}{\color{mathematicaprintcolor}\mathbox{\rule{0mm}{0mm}}}       % newline with correct indentation, only for printouts! (different color)
%\newcommand{\matherr}{\mathbox{\rule{0mm}{0mm}}\scriptsize\color{mathematicaerrorcolor}}
\newcommand{\matherr}[1]{\mathbox{\rule{0mm}{0mm}}\scriptsize\color{mathematicaerrorcolor}#1\color{mathematicaprintcolor}: }
\newcommand{\mathecho}[1]{\mathbox{\rule{0mm}{0mm}}\scriptsize\color{mathematicaechocolor}\guillemotright{} #1\color{mathematicaprintcolor}}
\newcommand{\mm}[1]{{\color{mathematicacolor}\texttt{#1}}}
% make sure the line numbers don't get copied when copy-pasting Mathematica source code
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}{\tiny\color{mathematicalinenumbercolor}\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}\protect\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}

Abcedfg
\begin{mathematica}
    ¤protect¤mathin¤ sx¤ =¤ PauliMatrix[1];
    ¤protect¤mathin¤ Conjugate[up[¤mmtheta,¤mmphi]].sx.up[¤mmtheta,¤mmphi]¤ //ComplexExpand¤ //FullSimplify
\end{mathematica} 
\end{document}

Yes, it is not a little one, but I have no idea how to make it less without breaking it down.
I have a file 44.tex with this code and it works. Also, I have a file draft-latex.tex and it doesn't work. The code is the same! I have a message as follows:
Invalid UTF-8 byte "8E. \begin{mathematica}
Unicode character  (U+008F) not set up for use with LaTeX. \begin{mathematica}
Argument of \FancyVerbGetLine has an extra }. �
Paragraph ended before \FancyVerbGetLine was complete. �
Paragraph ended before \FV@CheckScan was complete. �
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. �
Can someone please explain, what is going on and how this is possible?
And, maybe, it is possible to fix it?
I use simple pdflatex on Windows and Texstudio: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "draft-latex".tex

If you copy everything over to a new file, does it work or not work?  You appear to have deleted too much, since what you have doesn't compile.  But you've also not deleted enough of the irrelevant parts.  You also seem to have somethings that suggest you're using pdflatex, and somethings that suggest lualatex or xelatex.  Which compiler are you using?

please copy error messages here as text. images can't be searched, can't be indexed and can't be parsed by screen reading software. perhaps you can read white on aqua but I can't. you have unicode characters latex doesn't recognise. you either need to tell latex about them or not use them. (or possibly switch engines.)

I have updated question

Well, ¤protect¤mathin¤ sx¤ =¤ PauliMatrix[1]; already shows up for me with chars the browser cannot render. If I put it into https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html it tells me they are U+00A4 : CURRENCY SIGN not sure what that is doing in your Mathematica code.

It looks like the TeX file isn't utf-8, but IsoLatin9 instead.  All sorts of characters have been messed up in that conversion.  I would recommend retyping everything yourself.

@Teepeemm But what do you mean by retyping? I am very confused because the same code in the same folder works in a file with one name and in another file with another name it doesn't work....

Something else has to be different.  Check the file encoding of the files (https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710374/2336725).  Retyping would be to open a new file and type in the characters without copy pasting anything.  How did you get the unreadable characters that daleif commented about?

@Teepeemm The full original file is runnable with three types of errors 1) encoding one file has utf-8 somewhere. This can be by-passed with   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \UseRawInputEncoding and siunix and fancyvrb are based on older versions. Ignoring all the errors I got the pdf.  Is an interesting publication though.

@yannisl I also get pdf, if I ignore errors, but instead of listing code, I see nothing...
